# Getting connection error while connecting to smart contract using web3.js

Tags: node.js, smartcontracts, web3js, ganache

I am using the guide at https://medium.com/@amkurian/interacting-with-ethereum-smart-contracts-through-web3-js-e0efad17977 to connect to a smart contract, where I want to access the get() method of the smart contract.

Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Web 3</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>First Smart Contract</h1>
            <h2 id="instructor"></h2>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Name</label>
            <input id="name" type="text">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Age</label>
            <input id="age" type="text">
            <button id="button">Update Instructor</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js "></script>
    
        <script>
            if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            }
            else {
                // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
                web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://my_ip_address:8545"));
            }
    
            web3.eth.defaultAccount = 'account address';
    
            var CoursesContract = web3.eth.contract(my abi);
    
            var Courses = CoursesContract.at('my smart contract address');
    
            console.log(Courses.getName());
    
        </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

But I'm getting the below error in the console:

> web3.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node

> http://my ip here:8545.
> at Object.InvalidConnection (web3.min.js:1)
> at i.send (web3.min.js:1)
> at s.send (web3.min.js:1)
> at _.e [as call] (web3.min.js:1)
> at c.call (web3.min.js:1)
> at c.execute (web3.min.js:1)
> at index.html:40

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `ganache-cli` and leave it running.

Replace `http://my_ip_address:8545` with `http://localhost:8545/`

This will resolve your problem.